# Generalize over iterators over references and iterators over values

Tags: reference, iterator, rust, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want to implement a trait for which one of the functions takes an iterator as an argument and then operates on the values returned by that iterator as immutable references.

However I would also like my function to work on iterators over values as well (without having to duplicate code).  How can I do that?

The following does not work:

```
impl<T, I: Iterator> FilterItem for SortedFilter<I> where  T: Ord, I::Item: Borrow<T> {
    ...
}
```

I get

```
error: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`Borrow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait:

> When writing generic code, it is often desirable to abstract over all ways of borrowing data from a given type

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn print_it<I, T>(iter: I)
    where I: Iterator<Item = T>,
          T: Borrow<u8>
{
    for v in iter {
        let a: &u8 = v.borrow();
        println!("{}", a);
    }
}


fn main() {
    let vals = vec![1,2,3];
    print_it(vals.iter()); // Iterator of references
    print_it(vals.into_iter()); // Iterator of values
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that I'm actually implementing a trait and also, the type of the item is generic.

Comment: Please take another look

Comment: @dspyz I think that update completely changes the question. You can update your title to reflect your much more complicated specific instance or rollback your changes and ask a followup question.